# Difference between calling watcher with parentheses vs without

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-options-api

In watch property, what is the difference between calling property using `()` and not using them?

```js
export default {
  watch: {
    // syntax with ()
    test() {
      if (this.test) {
        //some work
      } else {
        //some work
      }
    },

    // syntax without ()
    labels: {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler(option) {
        //some work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Futhermore what is the aim of `immediate` and `deep`?

Comment: Your questions are all answered by the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html).  Handler is necessary if you want to use any of the watcher options (`immediate` and `deep` ), otherwise, the first syntax option is simply slightly faster to write

Answer (score 0):

`watch` is lazy by default, meaning it would only run after an initial change to the source has occurred.

adding `immediate: true` essentially let's the callback of the watch to run when the component is initialized. In essence, like the `do` block of a `do while` loop in certain languages.

you can find more and the deep and eager watch at the docs
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html